# Puxar Json de arquivo externo com Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Eu estou fazendo um projeto e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.

Eu estou tentando pegar o Json de um arquivo externo com Javascript puro e exibir no console via console.log, mas não estou conseguindo, pois, recebo o seguinte erro no console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Não encontrei nenhum erro no código por isso eu irei deixar ele abaixo para vocês poderem vê-lo:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs'

readFile('../tmp/list.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) { 
        console.log("File read failed:", err)
        return
    }
    console.log('File data:', jsonString) 
})
```

Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Comment: Substitua `import { readFile } from 'fs'`  por `const { readFile } = require('fs');`

Answer (score 2):

Desta maneira só vai funcionar se estiver usando a sintaxe de módulos de javascript (ESM) [node.js >= 14.0]. Para isso mude a extensão do arquivo para `.mjs`. Caso não queira mudar a extensão do arquivo para `mjs` ainda é possível modificar o seu `package.json` e adicionar a seguinte linha `"type": "module"` de forma que ficaria mais ou menos desta forma:

```
{
  //...
  "name": "minha-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

Caso queira fazer o seu código funcionar usando a sintaxe do *"Common JS"* então é necessário fazer algumas mudanças em seu código, como o @Augusto Vasques sugeriu. Temos que utilizar as palavras chave `require` e se quisermos exportar funções fazemos através da palavra chave `module.exports` ou `exports`.

Mudanças necessárias para o executar o código em `Common JS`:

```
const { readFile } = require('fs'); //<-- Mudança aqui

readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) { 
        console.log("File read failed:", err)
        return
    }
    console.log('File data:', jsonString) 
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta agregou valor a pergunta. Muito boa.

Comment: Esta solução seria para caso eu estivesse usando node.js?                       Pois, eu estou fazendo isso Javascript puro.